# having an image thumbnail size exactly across browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to come up with a script that will have a number of thumbnails across (in width) the browser. I want it to be able to be flush and not have gaps on the sides. The thumbnails should always be the same size, and I'm guessing that the only way is the change the spacing between each image. But can someone help me out? Let me know if my question is unclear.

EDIT: here's an example: http://www.beautyineverything.com/

Thank you!

Comment: the question is unclear. Do you mean that you want a page filled with thumbnails with no gaps in between? want to add some markup so we can look at it? what have you tried?

Comment: well I know that I can use <ul><li></li></ul> tags and float:left; add paddings or margins, but in the end, before it gets to the next row, you can imagine that there will be a larger gap  (or white space) between the image and the right side of the browser. I'm trying to make all the spaces even, even if the browsers' width gets reduced, there will still be even spaces

Comment: why use `<ul><li>` tags? why not just float the `<img>` tags? Do you want the images to go past the right side of the page? (as in hidden off to the right so there is no gap?) do you have any examples?

Comment: set the width property to a fixed size: 200px; and you are set for life

Comment: Do you want to keep even space between the images in all the rows? What if the image count do not match between the rows?

Comment: @andrew look at the css/markup on http://fixoutlook.org

Comment: I was trying to look for this site and I found it!! its like this site, http://www.beautyineverything.com/

Comment: @andrewli You should try and solve it your self first. You'll get more help that way. Take a look at the javascript/css on that page.

Comment: @andreliu Thats what makes the challenge interesting. When you've had a try come back and post what you got and what did/did not work.

Comment: In their html they have `<body onload="make_photos();" onresize="make_photos();">` which undoubtedly does the magic. I would recommend looking at this function and trying to replicate it. If you are unable to, report back here :)

Comment: Thanks for posting this, btw, I had no idea their was an event handler for window's resize and this will definitely help on my website.

Comment: I'm glad I at least helped someone out with my question haha :)

Comment: Seems to be easy to accomplish. There's list of `block` elements (might be `li`, `div`, `a` or anything else) with centered background that is wider than element. If you resize window so that there's only one column, you will see that background is 2 or even 3 times wider than container, when there are more columns. When window resizes, all these elements are resized by using quite simple math - `width of image = width of window / number of images`. If result is too small, make `number of images` smaller and repeat. If result is too large, make it bigger and repeat.

Comment: By the way, it has nothing to do with PHP and ajax (removed them from tags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
<head>
    <title>sandbox</title>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH = 240;

        $(function(){
            $(window).resize(resizeImages).resize();
        });

        function resizeImages() {
            var containerWidth = $('.imageContainer').innerWidth();
            var numberOfImages = Math.ceil(containerWidth / MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH);
            var imageWidth = Math.ceil(containerWidth / numberOfImages);
            var imageWidthLast = containerWidth - (numberOfImages - 1) * imageWidth;
            $('.imageContainer .image').css('width', imageWidth);
            $('.imageContainer .image:nth-child(' + numberOfImages + 'n)').css('width', imageWidthLast);

            $('.imageContainer .image').each(function(){
                $(this).text($(this).innerWidth());
            });
        }
    </script>
    <style type='text/css'>
        .imageContainer {
            border:1px solid black;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .image {
            width:160px;
            height:160px;
            float:left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='imageContainer'>
        <?php
            for ( $n = 10; $n < 30; ++$n) {
                $backgroundColor = '#' . sprintf('%02x%02x%02x', $n * 8, $n * 8, $n * 8);
                echo "<div class='image' style='background-color:{$backgroundColor};'></div>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Resizing images could be written in a bit smarter way so that instead of `223+223+223+223+223+223+223+216` they would be `223+222+222+222+222+222+222+222`. For this, width of each *column* should be calculated individually, so that widths of columns vary only by 1px max.

Comment: Thanks for posting this!! I'm trying this, but I think I'm missing something because I dont think its working for me? +1 for example!

Comment: the images, its not resizing, its as if the images are fixed size and then when the browser resizes (gets smaller) the image that can't fit in that row anymore just goes to next line and it has a gap.

Comment: Images will not resize, their containers will. You have to create block elements (might be `<a style='display:block;'></a>` or just `<div/>`) and set images as their backgrounds with `style='background:transparent url(images/imageXXX.jpg) no-repeat center center;'`. Images have to be at least as big as max size of container, i.e., if max width of container is 240px, image has to be at least 240px wide. When container is smaller, only part of image will be visible.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound primitive but tables were designed for something like this only.
one solution is to have a table and put your images as background-image of the cells. (or put it inside and give it a height and width 100%) Its is easy to keep control over the cell size and margins/padding.. that is why they were so popular for structural stuff.

Before ruling the idea out, do note that (apart form the fact that i HATE to use tables for designing and positioning stuff, but do not hesitate to use it for what it was meant to be) making tables will reduce the amount of code to be written. use css to size the cells and table. use inline to put background image. no js functions wat-so-ever.

please drop a comment if you disagree of if i am missing something :)

Comment: You're missing something. There are 2 problems - gaps and variable number of elements in each row. Try changing width of window and see what happens with last images of each row.

Comment: if we use % instead of fixed numbers for cell and table widths (and height of course), the cells will shift when they reach their max-width/min-width;

and for gaps, you can set cell padding or what ever it is..

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood what you mean. Could you post some simple HTML/CSS to illustrate it, please?

Comment: ok tables were crap but i have a proof of concept..  

`span {width:7%; float:left; max-width:100px; min-width:70px;}`  

now the html  

`<body><span>foo</span></body>`

you need alot of those foo spans, i am not adding them because it will take space.  

note: the thing does not work if you size the window too small.. like 400px or something like that. but it is just a proof of concept. its just how we fine tune the math.  

do that in a window (chrome). now resize the window. but not too small. at least a thousand px. (remember just a proof of concept.) do let me know what do you think :)

Comment: It does not work with neither too small nor too big containers. When last item is being dropped to the next line, all other items on the same line have to fill that space. When new item is being added to the next line, all other items have to get smaller to make a space for that last item. There's also some gap at the end of line, when spans are in "resizing state". E.g., with container being 1279px wide, there are 14 spans with 90px width and 19px gap after them.

Comment: yes but that is solely because of the math. the logic will be the same. essentially, the max-width of the image has to be just enough to cover for the loss of a one less item in the row but not too much to overflow the line again. as i said, i just proved that it is possible. of course there are limitations but maybe you can credit it to be pure css.. :)

Comment: What logic? There are serious problems with this, uhm, "logic" :) Grid elements have to stack correctly and be able to resize (i.e., fill the width of container) at the same time. This "pure CSS" solution either does stacking with no resizing (if container is too small or too large), or does resizing with no stacking (if width of container is within some range). If everyone used the same resolution of monitor, this might work, but this is not going to work in a world where some use netbooks/tablets/phones, while others use 24" FullHD monitors.

Comment: alright.. no probs.. he didnt implement it anyways.. so no harm done i guess.